# Score remains same during hyper parameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

My model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input_1))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    #model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])
```

Now, I am doing hyper parameter tuning, but it is showing the same for every possible result:

```
Best: -61101.514139 using {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 2}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 2}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 4}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 5}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 10}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 15}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 2}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 4}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 5}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 10}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 15}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 2}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 4}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 5}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 10}
-61101.514139 (25108.783936) with: {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 15}
```

This is the first time I have done hyper parameter tuning before and this has stumped me. I can provide additional details if needed. What is a possible reason for this behavior?

I am doing time series forecasting using MLP. I have used 'neg_mean_absolute_error as the scoring function in gridsearchCV.

Edit: this is what Im running:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# define the grid search parameters
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=1)
batch_size = [10,20,2000]
epochs = [2,4,5,10, 25]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(scaled_train,scaled_train_y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

Comment: Is the negative mean absolute error shown the error on the train or the validation set?

Comment: Those are quite large values for mae; what's the scale of your output?  As a first guess, perhaps the network just isn't learning anything at all.

Comment: @Oxbowerce i added the code

Comment: @BenReiniger from 100,000 to 200,000

Comment: @ubuntu_noob what does the `create_model` function look like?

Comment: @Oxbowerce I have already added the model I am using

Comment: Try scaling your target variable?

Comment: @BenReiniger I tried that..it was almost the same result

Comment: Are you sure Relu is a good choice?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following changes,

1. Try KerasRegressor instead of KerasClassifier.
2. Use other activation functions than relu (Eg: tanh, or just linear)
3. Normalize both target and regressors.